# explicit function between transformation matrix and vertex in polyhedron

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, algebraic-geometry, optimization

recently I am stuck in solving a geometric problem. I hope someone could give me some tips, thanks for all in advance!!!

**Question 1**: given a **constant** polygon $M1$ with 4 vertices: $(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(0,0)$, a **variable** point $p1: ({ x_{0} , y_{0} })$ and a **variable** matrix: $H\in \mathbb{R^{2\times 2}}$.

If a linear transformation using $H$ is conducted to polygon $M1$ and point $p1$, we will get a transformed polygon $M2$ together with point $p2$.

e.g.  in the picture below, the red **constant** polygon $M1$ with a **random generated** red point $p1= (0.58,0.22)$,  a **random generated** $H=\begin{bmatrix}0.12& 0.96\\0.5&0.34\end{bmatrix}$, after transformation $ \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 & 1& 0& 0.58\\0 & 0 & 1&1& 0.22 \end{bmatrix}^T   \cdot \begin{bmatrix}0.12& 0.96\\0.5&0.34\end{bmatrix} $, we will get the blue transformed polygon $M2$ and the blue point $p2$.

[image: a small example with the optimal vertex (1,0)]

The question is, is it possible to establish a function, so that for an **arbitrary given** point $p1$ and an **arbitrary given** matrix $H$, the proper vertex in polygon $M1$, which after transformation has the minimal Euclidean distance to point $p2$, could be directly found. Here vertex $(1 , 0)$ in $M1$ corresponds to the vertex in $M2$ that is nearest to point $p2$. It can be formed as an equation as below:

$min \quad d(v\cdot H,p2) = f(H,p1),  \quad v\in M1,  \quad p2 =p1 \cdot H$

I just want to build an explicit function or look-up table of above implicit constraints.

PS: distance is considered **only in polygon $M2$** , not in $M1$, exact distance value is not required, an optimal vertex in $M1$ is already enough, e.g. vertex (1,0) in the image

**Question 2**: above is just 2d situation, if we extend polygon $M1$ to polyhedron $MP1$ in n dimensions, how would the function look like? Each dimension of the vertex contains always 0 or 1.

e.g. the vertex would be like (1,0,1) in 3d and (1,0,1,1) in 4d. For n dimensions there would be in total $2^n$ vertices in polyhedron $MP1$.

Point $p1$ is still a variable in n dimensions and the transformation matrix $H \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$

---

**UPDATE:**  A small example to demonstrate that the closest vertex to $p1$ in $M1$ may not be the closest one to $p2$ in $M2$.

Consider $p1 = (0.6,0.4)$ and $H = \begin{bmatrix}0.8 & 1 \\-0.8 & 0 \end{bmatrix} $, then the plot shows as follows:

[image: a small counterexample]

I am not sure if this problem can be solved efficiently, one guess is that it may be related to the ***Singular Value Decomposition***.
If $H$ is just an upper or lower triangular matrix, would it be a little easier to get the function?

Any idea or guess will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It is just an educated guess, but I think you may get somewhere by playing with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I think it may be related to Singular Value Decomposition. Also a guess. :)